# What's wrong with my animation in css3?

Tags: css

I cannot figure out why my css3 is not animating.  Please help.  I have the div and @keyframes set. 
    
    
    
    test
        
            div {
                animation: test 4s;
            }

```
        @keyframes test {
            0% {
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: red;
            }

            100% {
                bottom: 50px;
                left: 350px;
                background-color: blue;
            }
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

    <div>
        Text
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to apply it to the div:

```
div {
  animation: test 1s;
}
```

And also use prefixed css for Chrome and Safari:

```
@-webkit-keyframes test {
        0% {
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: red;
        }

        100% {
            bottom: 50px;
            left: 350px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    }

@keyframes test {
        0% {
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: red;
        }

        100% {
            bottom: 50px;
            left: 350px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    }

div {
-webkit-animation: test 1s;
        animation: test 1s;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with vendor prefixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/zahanq0g/

To check which properties work with which browsers I recommend using Can I Use. E.g: http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes

Comment: Google Chrome ver 41. i thought supported animatin out of the box

Comment: Tried the fiddle.  Not working in my browser. How do I target for chrome 41?